# get index of a specific string along with the string in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

```
Dim str() as string = "1,2,1,2"
```

From the above string array i want to know the repeating string's index like "1" is at index of 0,2 and "2" at 1,3. How to do this in  vb.net?

Please keep in mind that i will get the string array from database. so i dont which numbers are present more than 2 times.

Comment: thats not a valid declaration for an array.  did you mean `Dim str As String() = {"1", "2", "1", "2"}`?

Comment: bro actually its not an array. Its a string value each and everytime i will add "," depends upon the database record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to `Split` the string after you get it from the database so you'll have an array.

Then you'll want to know all the `Distinct` values that are in the array so you can search through and find the indexes.

```
Imports System

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim str() As String = "1,2,1,2,3,1,0,1,4".Split(","c)
        ' Get the distinct values from the string array
        Dim uniqueNumbers = str.Distinct()

        ' Loop through the distince values and find what indexes they are located at
        For Each uniqueNumber In uniqueNumbers
            Dim indexValues As New List(Of Integer)
            For index = 0 To str.Length - 1
                If (uniqueNumber = str(index)) Then
                    indexValues.Add(index)
                End If
            Next

            ' Ouput the results of the distinct value
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is at indexes {1}", uniqueNumber, String.Join(", ", indexValues.ToArray()))
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
1 is at indexes 0, 2, 5, 7
2 is at indexes 1, 3
3 is at indexes 4
0 is at indexes 6
4 is at indexes 8
```

### Shorter Code

```
Imports System

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim str() As String = "1,2,1,2,3,1,0,1,4".Split(","c)
        Dim uniqueNumbers = str.Distinct()

        For Each uniqueNumber In uniqueNumbers
            Dim indexValues = str.Select(Function(s, i) New With {i, s}).Where(Function(t) t.s = uniqueNumber).Select(Function(t) t.i)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is at indexes {1}", uniqueNumber, String.Join(", ", indexValues.ToArray()))
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

### Shortest Code

```
Imports System

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim str() As String = "1,2,1,2,3,1,0,1,4".Split(","c)
        str.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(Sub(u) Console.WriteLine("{0} is at indexes {1}", u, String.Join(", ", str.Select(Function(s, i) New With {i, s}).Where(Function(t) t.s = u).Select(Function(t) t.i).ToArray())))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Explanation of shortest code:

```
1. The `String` "1,2,1,2,3,1,0,1,4" gets broken into a `String Array` using the comma as the delimiter.
 2. `str.Distinct()` returns a collection of unique values from the `String Array`. 
    2.1. Adding the `.ToList()` takes the collection of unique values and turns it into a `List` object.
    2.2. Adding the `.ForEach()` iterates through each item in the list.  Each item is stored in the variable "u" which is defined by `Sub(u)`.  We use `Sub` instead of `Function` because what is happening in the `ForEach` will not be returning a value.  Instead we display to the screen `Console.WriteLine()`.
    2.3.  Console.WriteLine takes a formatted String `"{0} is at indexes {1}"`.  The `{0}` and `{1}` are place holders for variables to fill in.
    2.4.  Place holder {0} is replaced by the "u" variable which will be whatever unique number the `.ForEach` is on.  Place holder {1} is replaced by the String.Join operation which is figuring out all the index locations of the variable "u".
    2.5.  `String.Join()` combines an array into a single `String` separated by a delimiter (In this case, ", " is the delimiter).
    2.6.  The array is created by `str.Select(Function(s, i) New With {i, s}).Where(Function(t) t.s = u).Select(Function(t) t.i).ToArray()`
        2.6.1.  The .Select(Function(s, i) New With {i, s}) is returning a collection of index values (i variable) for the unique letter (s variable).
        2.6.2.  The .Where(Function(t) t.s = u) filters the collection from 2.6.1 to index values and unique letter where the in variable s matches the unique letter (u) from the `.ForEach()` in 2.2.  
        2.6.3.  The last `.Select(Function(t) t.i)` return a collection of just the index values that were found for the unique letter.
        2.6.4.  The `.ToArray()` transforms the collection made from 2.6.1 - 2.6.3 into an `Array`, that the `String.Join()` transforms into a single string separated by ", ".
```

Comment: thank u so much bro. but is there any possible to reduce code length???

Comment: bro i'm new to vb.net. can u say how to run code in "Module"???

Comment: @nasr18 This is a sample console application

Comment: @nasr18 You're welcome...  If you found my answer helpful, kindly click the check mark to my answer and consider up voting it. :-)

Comment: did bro. but is there any way to reduce the code length??? @Shar1er80

Comment: bro, why does the code length matter???

Comment: bro, if you can't do it in three lines or less, it's too complicated, bro.  ;-)

Comment: @nasr18 You're going to have to use the sample I've provided and adjust accordingly to your windows application.  I assume you want to display the results in a TextBox or a MessageBox, so instead of writing to the Console, as in my sample, you would append to a string and set the string to the TextBox or whatever you are using to display the results.

Comment: @Shar1er80 excellent bro. u forget to explain this line too...... "String.Join(", ", str.Select(Function(s, i) New With {i, s}).Where(Function(t) t.s = u).Select(Function(t) t.i).ToArray()"

Comment: @Shar1er80 you are superb bro. Is private chat available in StackOver flow. I'm new to this StackOver Flow.

Comment: @Shar1er80 bro u there???

Comment: @nasr18 Yes, What's up?

Comment: @Shar1er80 bro instead of writing the output to console or message box..... how to write it to text box or label or any other control????